# Grammar where the precedence of condition operators are asymmetric with regard to assignment operators

Tags: formal-grammars, programming-languages

In Unix shell programming, there's the ideom:

```
program1 && program2 && program3
```

where successful completion of `program1` and then `program2` will lead to the execution of `program3`.

In Perl, there's 2 set of condition operators - punctuation styles `&&`, `||`, etc., which binds more closely; and keyword style `and`, `or`, etc., which binds more loosely (precedence below assignment operators).

Yesterday, I write this in C:

```
yesno && pointer += offset;
```

trying to achieve this: if `yesno` is true, `pointer` is advanced by an offset, otherwise, no action is taken. Of couse this failed because condition operators binds more closely than assignments and the expression became:

```
(yesno && pointer) += offset;
```

which is invalid since the left-side of the assignment is no longer an lvalue.

Question:

Of course, if there's a programming language with grammar that makes it legal, it would create whole lot of problem designing a compiler for it and write correct and efficient codes in it.

But for curiosity, I'd like to know is it possible to define a grammar such that make it possible to do:

- advance `pointer` by an offset with:

```
yesno && pointer += offset;
```

and

- assign boolean predicate to a variable:

```
cond = input_ready && output_ready;
```

Comment: Sure. There's no rule that says that the left and right precedences have to be similar.

Comment: @rici, I know. I've read the drafts of the C standards and know how precedences (and left/right-associativity) are defined in terms of nested non-terminal symbols. I'll come up with a solution in context-free grammar in spare time if nobody else does.

Comment: Your question was just "is it possible". It is possible. If you want someone to do the work for you, you'll have to ask them to do that. :-) But my free time is perhaps more limited than yours.

Comment: @rici True. But if someone just literally answer "it's possible" without demonstrating or proving it, it wouldn't be an interesting and up-vote-able answer.

Comment: Which is why it's a comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be asking for is for assignment and `&&` to have *different* relevant precedence depending on which occurs on the left or the right -- `=` has higher precedence when it is to the left of the `&&` and lower when it is to the right.

This turns out to be remarkably hard to do with a traditional "pure" CFG, but fairly straight-forward to do with yacc's precedence declarations.  The key to that is to realize that "precedence" in yacc really isn't about operations, it is about rules and tokens -- whenever a shift/reduce conflict occurs, it compares the precedence of the token to be shifted with that of the rule to be reduced and it does whichever is higher.

To have different precedence for on-the-left vs on-th-right, you just need difference precedences for the rule and the token, which you can do with a `%prec` directive.  For your example, something like:

```
%nonassoc ASSIGN_LOW
%left ANDAND
%right '='

%%

expr: expr '=' expr %prec ASSIGN_LOW
    | expr ANDAND expr
    | primary
    ;
```

This gives a higher precedence to an `=` token than an `&&` (or the rule with `&&` which gets that precedence by default), so when an `=` appears to the right, it has higher precedence.  But the full `expr '=' expr` *rule* has lower precedence, so the `=` on the left will be lower precedence.

This has a side effect that `=` will always be right recursive, even if you used `%left` or `%nonassoc` for it, as the `=` *rule* has lower precedence than the `=` *token*.  I used `%right` here for clarity.  If you did something where a rule had higher precedence that its token, that would always be effectively left-recursive.

---

To address the comment in the other answer, this still has issues with something like

```
A && B = C && D = E
```

which will be parsed as

```
A && (B = (C && (D = E)))
```

which might not be what you want.  There's not a good way of dealing with that as it would require looking at more context to determine the precedence.

Answer (score -1):

No. At least not unambiguously with context-free grammar.

Take the following grammar fragment as an example:

```
## preliminary
def assign-op # assignment operator
: ...
; 

def unary-expr # uniary expression
: ...
;

## main grammar

def arith-expr # arithmetic expression
: ...
;

def logic-expr # logical expression
: arith-expr
| logic-expr ( "&&" | "||" ) arith-expr
;

def assign-expr # assignment expression
: logic-expr
| unary-expr assign-op assign-expr
;
```

In `assign-expr`, the lvalue is already defined as an unary expression. The problem with compiler issuing error is that, `yesno && pointer += offset` is parsed as:

```
yesno && pointer      +=        offset
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      ||        ||||||
(  logic-expr  )      vv        vvvvvv
(expecting:unary-expr assign-op assign-expr)
```

where the assignment expression is expecting an unary expression but a logical expression was present.

Also, consider:

```
cond1 && ptr1 = buf && ptr1 += offset;
```

where the expected behavior is

> set `ptr1` to `buf + offset` if `cond1` is true and `buf` is not `NULL`.

If the proposed asymmetric precedence is realized, this expression would become essentially nonsense.

These can all be worked around with either a more complex grammar, or a non-conventional parser, but as explained in the question, this would make writing correct and efficient programs very difficult

Comment: Hi. I don't understand why `cond1 && ptr1 = buf && ptr1 += offset` would be nonsense? I think it should be parsed as `cond1 && (ptr1 = (buf && (ptr1 += offset)))`. Basically `=` and `&&` have the same priority but are right-associative.